# Flag/Close menu won't open after interface update

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flags, vote-to-close

I noticed today we got a new interface for closing/flagging.  Almost immediately after getting it though, both the close vote and flag menus won't load anymore.  The little black dots just go on forever.

Example from random question:

[image]

Example from the close vote queue:

[image]

I see this on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), does anyone else experience this?  I'm using Chromium, and the issue persists after clearing site data.

Comment: What browser? Did you clear your cache, force a reload? I flagged and voted with the new UI just fine so far.

Comment: Any errors in the console?  Some javascript changes went out, but I can't reproduce this error.

Comment: This happened to me as well, but after a few force reloads everything worked fine.

Comment: Another clearing of site data seems to have fixed it my end, I'll see if it comes back.

Comment: I hit this as well, though it went away after a hard refresh. Shouldn't have had to do that, but obviously things are a bit jumpy tonight.

Comment: @Shog9 Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Doesn't really answer anything... I'm as perplexed as you!

Comment: I have posted my report [separately](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166421/flag-interface-insta-closes), as it largely seems to be different now.