# Flag interface insta-closes

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

Okay, a seemingly very simple problem:

I go to any question anywhere on the network. I try to flag it. The first dialogue opens just fine:

[image]

Then, when I select the "it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate" option, it loads for a moment, then closes.

When I try again, I can select the option, but the subsequent dialogue doesn't show up, it is just stuck there with no indication of anything happening.

---

On the JS console, I get regular outputs of a connection error to `ws://sockets-se.or.stackexchange.com/`:

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://sockets-se.or.stackexchange.com/. @ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/full.js?v=b2fcf8c8b3aa:12

And when selecting the option on the dialogue, it reports an argument conversion error:

> NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle] @ http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:4

The same pattern also occurs on Ask Ubuntu. Force-refreshing, restarting the browser and even booting to a different OS do not fix this.

---

In addition to this, we also have [two](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7987254#7987254) [reports](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7987416#7987416) of other users on Ask Ubuntu facing the same issue.

Comment: +1 for investigating the issue in addition to reporting it.

Comment: Another bug presumably from the UI changes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166422/too-frequent-comment-error-message-is-showing-wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There may be a newline or two in the popup HTML, which creates a text node in the DOM. When switching the popups and thus fading out the old one, jQuery tries to fade out the text node. This [doesn't end well in some browsers](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12462). I'm deploying a fix for this as we speak.

Comment: Appears to work for me now, for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

Can confirm that this also happens on SharePoint Exchange - I actually created a post on meta there before finding out this is a common issue on all sites. If anyone wants to have a look the link is [here](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/794/possible-bug-on-the-flag-question-popup-screen). I will try to edit this answer if we find out something.

Anyway, I have tried to see if the IE dev toolbar reports anything worth. Just after the pop up self-closes I saw this.

[image]

Right now I can't have a look at it, so I am leaving it there for the time begin.