# Cancelling flagging leads to broken flagging dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, flag-dialog

Closing the flagging dialog can lead to a situation where it is broken until the page is reloaded. It can be reproduced like this:

- Press *flag* on a question.
- Select *it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate.*
- Close the resulting dialog
- Press *flag* again.
- Now pressing *it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate* doesn't open the close dialog. Clicking the text of the other options also doesn't work properly, but clicking the radio button itself works.

This happens on both Firefox and IE9.

Comment: Appears to be working fine in Chrome. Weird.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro]

Comment: @Doorknob: On which browser did you test it? I reproduced this on different computers, browsers, and operating systems.

Comment: Chrome Win7 (comment too short)

Comment: I also have no problem. I'm Running Chromium on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Doorknob and Seth: Well, Sha Wiz Dow Ard already said it works on Chrome. That doesn't make it status-norepro. The bug report is about Firefox and IE9.

Comment: Confirmed working fine with Safari on Mac. Testing with FF now...

Comment: Failing just as OP would suggest on FF for mac, v16.0.2. Here's a SS of the issue: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb4Gg.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were multiple problems here. One of them was a duplicate HTML id; the other one was the same issue as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166475/115866), just in a different place. Both fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine on Safari and Chrome on OSX but it doesn't work on FF like you said. Same on Windows as well.